# positioning elements when generating a PDF on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, pdf

I am generating a PDF in my ipad app and I need to add page breaks so I also ned to move elements before I render a second page.  For example my long tableview will need to be adjusted vertically before I render the second, third page, ect...

Creating the PDF is pretty simple and I have that part down and the first page is generating perfectly but wen I try and set my frame to move my tableview for the next page nothing happens:

```
    -(void) createPDF {

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tmp.pdf"];

        CGContextRef pdfContext = [self createPDFContext:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height) path:(CFStringRef)writableDBPath];

        NSLog(@"PDF Context created");
        CGContextBeginPage (pdfContext,nil); // 6

        //turn PDF upsidedown
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, self.view.bounds.size.height);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0, -1.0);
        CGContextConcatCTM(pdfContext, transform);

        //Draw view into PDF
        self.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0,self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
        [self.view.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];

        CGContextEndPage (pdfContext);// 8

        CGContextBeginPage (pdfContext,nil);

        //turn PDF upsidedown
        CGContextConcatCTM(pdfContext, transform);

      // moving the table to an arbitrary position for testing, nothing happens in the PDF - view itself is updated
         self.itemsTableView.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
        [self.itemsTableView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];

        CGContextEndPage (pdfContext);// 8

        CGContextRelease (pdfContext);
    }
```

Comment: does creating the new page of the pdf actually work? It's such a pain figuring this library out. good luck.

Comment: what do you mean by "moving the table to an arbitrary position for testing, nothing happens in the PDF"? Since you render the view content in the PDF, the view's position within the superview has no effect on the rendering.

Comment: @Jesse - yes creating the page works like a charm. @iPDFdev - that makes sense - so how do I position it in the PDF view context then?

Comment: You need to apply a translate transform on the PDF context to move the coordinate system at the desired position.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an option for your app to use a cloud service to create the PDF, have a look at [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com).  The PDF is based on a document template so you can control page breaks etc without calculating it in code. Your app has to send the request and the data to populate the document and deliver the PDF so it relies on being connected.